# Load only new or updated css classes as page load finishes

Tags: css, ajax

Cached css file is loading on page load, i want to load only new or updated css classes through an ajax request. Like in git repository we can easily get difference between two file version. Please help me in this.

Comment: I want to load cached css file on page load but as soon as page loads, i want to load fresh css file. and if its possible i want to load only difference of code between cached and fresh css file.

Answer (score 0):

Just add a random query string for your css file like `...styles.css?v1` on every edit.

or if you are using php or any other server side language add timestamp or random number as querystring  `styles.css?<?=time();?>`

Comment: Sorry dear, there is some misunderstanding in my problem statement and proposed solution.